# Can’t find the right impact parameter - flux of particles scattered by surface of revolution

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I’ll be so happy to understand what am I doing wrong.
There is no potential in the question so I assumed this is solvable by geometry alone. The question ask for the impact parameter while

$$\rho=\sqrt{x^2+ y^2}$$

and

$$z=\frac{\rho^2}{2a}$$

The correct answer is $$b=a\cdot\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

But my geometry got me somewhere else, would you mind take a look?[image]

Comment: Hello! I have provided an edit to your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Oh wow, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer deliberately omits detailed working out, as the question could be regarded as homework-like.

It would seem that you are throwing missiles at a paraboloid of revolution in a direction parallel to its axis, so that they hit the convex surface of the paraboloid with impact parameter $b$ with respect to the vertex. Working this out was part of the fun of trying to answer the question!

I made use of the well-known theorem that if the path of incidence is parallel to the axis of a parabola, then if the law of reflection is obeyed, the path of reflection is directly away from the focus. For your parabola the focus is $\frac a2$. Having drawn a diagram you'll see that the angle, $\theta$, to the axis of the path of reflection is given by
$$\tan\theta=\frac{2ab}{b^2-a^2}=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}$$
in which $t=\frac ab$.
But you'll recognise that $t$ such that $\tan\theta=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}$ is none other than $\tan \frac{\theta}{2}$ !

Comment: Thank you Philip I’m going to try and work it out

Comment: @Yarin Shani  An alternative method would be to use a little calculus to find the slope of the normal to the paraboloid at the point of impact, ($b^2/2a,\  b$). The result you're looking for follows immediately from this.

Comment: Oh yeahh, you are the bomb!!